# Find the general solution of the differential equation $xy'' + y' = 4x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I began by rewriting this differential equation as:
$$ \frac { x \frac {d}{dx} w(x) + w(x) } {x} = 4$$
This has the form $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$ and so $$ \frac {dw} {w} = -P(x)dx$$
Integrating this yields $w= \frac {C}{x}$ and thus $$ \frac {d}{dx}C(x) = 4x$$ so $C(x) = 2x^2 + C$.
But I'm not sure how to proceed with the rest of the solution. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I got that from setting $P(x) = \frac {1}{x}$ and $Q(x) = 4$, then solving the correspondent linear homogenous equation $y' + P(x)y = 0$. But actually the problem doesn't require this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not that wrong :
$$xy'' + y' = 4x$$
$$xw' + w = 4x$$
Solve the homogeneous equation:
$$xw'=-w$$
$$\ln w =-\ln x +C$$
$$\implies w=\dfrac {C(x)}{x}$$
Substitute this in the original DE:
$$x(\dfrac {C(x)}{x})'+\dfrac {C(x)}{x}=4x$$
$$x(\dfrac {C'(x)x-C(x)}{x^2})+\dfrac {C(x)}{x}=4x$$
$$C'(x)=4x$$
Integrate:
$$C(x)=2x^2+C$$
Therefore:
$$W=\dfrac {2x^2+C}{x}$$
$$W=2x +\dfrac Cx$$
Since $w=y'$ we have
$$y'=2x +\dfrac Cx$$
Integrate:
$$\boxed {y(x)=x^2 + C_1 \ln x+C_2}$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the relation between $C(x)$ and $W$ - that is where I was getting stuck!

Comment: You're welcome @pinkUnicorn999 The method you used works fine...

Answer (score 4):

I can't follow your steps.

Instead, note that $xy'' + y' = (xy')'$, and the equation $$(xy')' = 4x$$ can be solved for $y$ by integration and basic algebra.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! I was making this problem much more complicated than necessary it seems.

Answer (score 1):

> $$x y'' + y' = 4 x$$

The rewrite in the question statement is not correct, but rather it replaces $y'$ with $y$, giving a different differential equation.

One *can* set $u := y'$, on the other hand and so write the equation as a first order one,
$$x u' + u = 4 x ,$$
and apply the standard technique of looking for an integrating factor.

**Hint** Alternatively, notice that the left-hand side of the equation can already be written as $$(xy')' = 4 x ,$$
(i.e., we need not introduce an integrating factor), and integrating gives
$$x y ' = 2 x^2 + C,$$
which reduces the problem to rearranging and computing an antiderivative.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that fact. My attempted solution overcomplicated the problem far too much.